# Save DIV as an image while preserving CSS filters?

Tags: html, css, html2canvas

A DOM element with the CSS attributes `filter` and `mask-image` has been applied.

 If there is a way to save that DOM element as an image while still preserving the functionality of all the applied CSS rules, please let me know.

 Unfortunately, the `filter` and `mask-image` features are not supported by **'html2canvas'** .

*Is it currently possible to accomplish this or is there any method to do so?*

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to take a screenshot. The image you see is a result of an image + some CSS, technically speaking it is not an image but an interpretation from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply CSS filters to an image captured using html2canvas by following these steps:

1. Use html2canvas to capture the desired image element. In this
   example, we are capturing the first child image element with the ID
   "my".
2. Create a new canvas element and obtain its 2D rendering
   context.
3. Apply CSS filters to the new canvas. In this example, we are
   applying a grayscale filter.You can apply other CSS filters using
   the same approach. For example, you can apply a blur filter or
   adjust brightness.
4. Set the dimensions of the new canvas to match the captured canvas.
5. Draw the captured image onto the new canvas with filters applied.
6. Finally, you can access the resulting canvas with applied filters
   using newCanvas.toDataURL(), which returns the canvas as a
   base64-encoded PNG image.

   ```
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#my img:first-child")).then(canvas => {
      const newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = newCanvas.getContext("2d");

      // Apply CSS filters to the new canvas
      newCanvas.style.filter = "grayscale(100%)"; // Apply grayscale filter
      // You can apply other filters using the same approach
      // newCanvas.style.filter = "blur(5px)";
      // newCanvas.style.filter = "brightness(200%)";

      // Set the dimensions of the new canvas to match the captured canvas
      newCanvas.width = canvas.width;
      newCanvas.height = canvas.height;

      // Draw the captured image onto the new canvas with filters applied
      context.filter = newCanvas.style.filter;
      context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

      console.log(newCanvas.toDataURL())

    });
   ```

and thi will work like a charm on chrome but on safari you have to update it even more as simple .filter won't work

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#my img:first-child")).then(canvas => {
    const originalWidth = canvas.width;
    const originalHeight = canvas.height;

    const newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.width = originalWidth;
    newCanvas.height = originalHeight;
    const newContext = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

    newContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight);

    const imageData = newContext.getImageData(0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight);
    const data = imageData.data;

    // Apply GRAY
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        const red = data[i];
        const green = data[i + 1];
        const blue = data[i + 2];
        const gray = (0.33 * red) + (0.33 * green) + (0.33 * blue);

        data[i] = gray;
        data[i + 1] = gray;
        data[i + 2] = gray;
    }

    newContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    const imageValue = newCanvas.toDataURL();
})
```

Comment: Both of your answers today appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: In addition, please don't copy/paste the same answer on two different questions.  If you believe the same answer applies, it may be more appropriate to flag one as a duplicate of the other.  Thanks!